# Trying to deploy a next.js app on firebase, issue at the .env file level (probably)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, next-auth

I'm stuck trying to deploy a next.js app on Firebase.
There are 2 cases where the app works. For now the app only implements a Google authentication button.

If my `.env` file is set as follow :

```js
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID   = **************************
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = ***********************
NEXTAUTH_SECRET = ****************************
NEXTAUTH_URL= http://localhost:3000
```

Excecuting "npm run dev" will lauch the app without any problem (nothing in the console)

If my .env file is set as follow :

```js
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID   = **************************
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = ***********************
NEXTAUTH_SECRET = ****************************
NEXTAUTH_URL= http://localhost:5000
```

Excecuting "firebase serve" will lauch the app without any problem (nothing in the console)

But then, if I change NEXTAUTH_URL to my base URL , build and deploy

```js
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID   = **************************
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = ***********************
NEXTAUTH_SECRET = ****************************
NEXTAUTH_URL= https://my-web-app.web.app
```

First when clicking on the button, there will be no reaction and no error in the console,  and after a few minutes , this log in the browser console :

```js
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error Unexpected token 'T', "Timed out "... is not valid JSON 
{error: {…}, url: '/api/auth/session', message: `Unexpected token 'T', "Timed out "... is not valid JSON`}
client
: 
true
error
: 
{message: `Unexpected token 'T', "Timed out "... is not valid JSON`, stack: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'T', "Timed out "... is not valid JSON`, name: 'SyntaxError'}
message
: 
"Unexpected token 'T', \"Timed out \"... is not valid JSON"
url
: 
"/api/auth/session"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

I've checked for compatible version between Firebase and Next.
I know for sure that the Google cloud console is set properly.
Here is the file at app/api/auth/[...nextauth] :

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const handler = NextAuth({

  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,

});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Here is the button that is being clicked and work perfectly with localhost:3000 and 5000

```js
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"
export default function SignInButton() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
        Signed in as {session.user.email} <br />
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
      </>
    )
  }
  return (
    <>
      Not signed in <br />
      <button onClick={() => signIn("google")}>Sign in</button>
    </>
  )
  }
```

The "layout.js" root page :

```js
export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}> 
      <Provider >
      <SignInButton/> 


        {children}
 
      </Provider></body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

And the Providers.js component :

```js
"use client"

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"
import  {Session} from "next-auth"
const session = Session;
export default function Provider({
  children
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session} children={children}>
      {children}
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP !

Comment: did you find a solution to this? facing the same problem now

Comment: Hi, no, I did not find a solution either than migrate to Vercel and learn Mongo DB.

Comment: By the way, I finally understood WHY! you cannot set environnement variables on Firebase. The remote server needs the .env.local file and without these variables set on Firebase servers, the auth cannot work...Firebase has its own auth functions for auth. Now my app runs perfectly with Vercel and MongoDB and MongoDB